# Summary is not getting update sometimes while executing Jmeter Script in Non GUI Mode

Tags: cmd, jmeter

Sometimes the summary didn't get update while executing JMeter script in Non GUI Mode, Please find below data.

```
Starting the test @ Wed Jan 04 18:41:18 IST 2017 (1483535478893)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary +     28 in 00:00:11 =    2.5/s Avg:  3376 Min:  1991 Max:  7555 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 37 Started: 37 Finished: 0

summary +    192 in 00:00:30 =    6.4/s Avg:  5623 Min:   812 Max: 19523 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 137 Started: 137 Finished: 0

summary =    220 in 00:00:41 =    5.4/s Avg:  5337 Min:   812 Max: 19523 Err:     0 (0.00%)

summary +    196 in 00:00:30 =    6.6/s Avg:  9388 Min:   813 Max: 46485 Err:     1 (0.51%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0

summary =    416 in 00:01:11 =    5.9/s Avg:  7246 Min:   812 Max: 46485 Err:     1 (0.24%)

summary +    159 in 00:00:31 =    5.2/s Avg: 11175 Min:   796 Max: 79142 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0

summary =    575 in 00:01:42 =    5.6/s Avg:  8332 Min:   796 Max: 79142 Err:     1 (0.17%)

summary +     50 in 00:00:29 =    1.7/s Avg: 39434 Min:   820 Max: 108309 Err:     1 (2.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0

summary =    625 in 00:02:11 =    4.8/s Avg: 10820 Min:   796 Max: 108309 Err:     2 (0.32%)

summary +    104 in 00:00:30 =    3.5/s Avg: 44422 Min:   846 Max: 125336 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 196 Started: 200 Finished: 4

summary =    729 in 00:02:41 =    4.5/s Avg: 15614 Min:   796 Max: 125336 Err:     2 (0.27%)

summary +    189 in 00:00:30 =    6.3/s Avg: 37163 Min:  5912 Max: 168988 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 172 Started: 200 Finished: 28

summary =    918 in 00:03:11 =    4.8/s Avg: 20051 Min:   796 Max: 168988 Err:     2 (0.22%)

summary +    208 in 00:00:30 =    6.9/s Avg: 27117 Min:  5369 Max: 180636 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 132 Started: 200 Finished: 68

summary =   1126 in 00:03:41 =    5.1/s Avg: 21356 Min:   796 Max: 180636 Err:     2 (0.18%)

summary +    232 in 00:00:30 =    7.7/s Avg: 34571 Min:  4706 Max: 220724 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 65 Started: 200 Finished: 135

summary =   1358 in 00:04:11 =    5.4/s Avg: 23614 Min:   796 Max: 220724 Err:     2 (0.15%)

summary +    171 in 00:00:30 =    5.7/s Avg: 21823 Min:  4524 Max: 220385 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 22 Started: 200 Finished: 178

summary =   1529 in 00:04:41 =    5.4/s Avg: 23413 Min:   796 Max: 220724 Err:     2 (0.13%)
```

The output is not shown after the last line, I wait up to 45 Min but logs are not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Few hints:

1. Check *jmeter.log* file for anything suspicious
2. Get thread dump using [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) or pressing Win + Break (on Windows) and check threads statuses, see if there are any deadlocked or looping processes
3. Use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) to attach to the process and inspect heap, see garbage collections, etc.
4. Check if anything is being added to .jtl results file

Most probably your JMeter instance isn't properly configured in terms of Java Heap size, Garbage Collection mode or your test plan has some issues.

References:

- [Troubleshooting Hanging or Looping Processes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/hangloop-140257.html)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: Thanks for info will look for provided solutions.